# How to unload program built from source in Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have downloaded the source code of bochs. and I use make install command to install it onto my box. But how could I uninstall it? I run the sudo apt-get remove bochs, but it said I didn't install the bochs...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do something like:

```
make uninstall
```

or

```
make remove
```

when you haven't used the package manager to do the original install.

Comment: Thanks Dennis. The make remove is not recognized. But the make unistall solve the problem. When I try to use "sudo apt-get remove bochs" to uninstall the bochs, the "man bochs" page still exists. But "make uninstll" can remove all of the locally built bochs, including the man page. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth using [CheckInstall](http://www.asic-linux.com.mx/~izto/checkinstall/) in future so that you can use your package manager to uninstall.

Comment: Thanks Cry. I read about the link as you suggested. It seems it should work for me. I will give it a try. Sorry I can mark only one reply as the answer.